# Where do I find an expert engineer or expert cook?

Tags: state-of-decay

In State of Decay, I have progressed to the point in construction and upgrades that it requires you to have an expert engineer or cook. **Where do I find someone who is an expert or how do I upgrade someone to become an expert?** I've noticed that the sheriff is a engineer, well at least I think he said so in a conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Survivor locations is randomized for each playthrough (I'm not sure about skills, but my guess is each character has a certain traits and skills template which is not random), so your best bet is to be friends with everyone to be able to recruit them and (hopefully) get the skills you want.

Comment: This is basically correct. There are survivor templates that are used to generate the random survivors available for recruitment. You can see an example one here: http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Survivors#Example. The skills you are looking for are http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Construction and http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Cooking, which are triggered by various traits mentioned on those pages. There aren't any survivors that are guaranteed to show up in a specific location with those skills in the base game.